# Replacing specific matrix element in numpy

Tags: python, linear-programming

I am trying to make a python code to complete the simplex algorithm for linear optimization (this is not for a class). I am using the numpy array. I want to replace the element in the (i,j) position with its reciprocal, how do I do this.

Comment: How is this question related to the simplex algorithm? If really all you want is to inverse the element ``(i,j)`` of an array ``x``, simply do ``x[i,j]=1/x[i,j]``. Assuming, of course, that ``x`` is of type ``float``. If this is not the case, first do ``x=x.astype(float)``.